# How to pass OrderBy(), Where() etc, as a parameter to process collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> li = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
        ProcessCollection(li, x => x);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> ProcessCollection<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> c, Func<TSource, TResult> lambdaexp)
    {
        return c.OrderBy(lambdaexp);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it takes a collection, process it and returns the new collection.  It currently processes collections by `OrderBy()` extention method.

I would like to extend this function so that it would take another (third) parameter as a function and apply this function on a collection passed as the first parameter. So far, I was trying to use combination of `Func<>` and `Action<>` but I couldn't work it out. I am still beginner.

Is it possible to define parameters of `ProcessCollection` such that it would process the collection according to a function passed as a parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need such a method at all if you could do `li.Orderby(i => i)` directly?

Comment: You would need to pass a reflected MethodInfo to the function, but the code needed is quite difficult and error prone for a beginner, I'd suggest you to rethink your code or explain better what you'd like to accomplish

Comment: I am trying to create a function (generic) that takes collections as the first parameter and another function as the second. In the body, the `ProcessCollection` would process incoming collections by applying passed function as the second parameter.

Comment: You're still describing your solution, not your problem. What is the problem you are trying to solve, and why do you think using a generic method helps you solve that problem? How do you want to *use* the method?

Comment: [XY Problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=xy+problem) perhaps

Comment: I have a generic `IRepository` interface and its concrete implementions. I also have one function that accepts repository objects. This function takes a repository object as one of the patrameters, get all items from the repository, process it, and return such collection. I though I could easily send another functon as another parameter and process what is retuned by the repository and eventually have returned the processed collection but I can see it is probably not very good approach. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: I did not want to come here with the whole code. That's why I make this question with very trivial problem but it helped me to understand the better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
static IEnumerable<TElemType> Process<TElemType>(IEnumerable<TElemType> source, 
    params Func<IEnumerable<TElemType>, IEnumerable<TElemType>>[] funcs)
{
    foreach(var func in funcs)
        source = func(source);

    return source;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
List<int> li = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
Process(li, x => x.OrderBy(y => y), x => x.Reverse());
```

But I'm not really sure why this is better than just doing:

`li.OrderBy(y => y).Reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

They have different signature, and the compiler must know what is the returned type in all time. Unless you want to work with **Explicit casting** and damage yourself in the process or better work with **Reflection**, I would suggest you to further consider what your trying to achieve and than think on a better solution to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, it's very simple:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> ProcessCollection<TSource,TResult>
  (IEnumerable<TSource> c, Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>> func)
{
    return func(c);
}
```

In other words, instead of passing a function that is applied to each of the elements, you pass a function that transforms the whole enumerable. You can than call it like this for example:

```
ProcessCollection(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }, c => c.OrderBy(i => i));
```

If you want to apply more transformations at the same time, just chain them together (that's what LINQ is, really):

```
ProcessCollection(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }, c => c.Select(i => i.ToString()).OrderBy(i => i));
```

Of course, this is pretty much useless. It does exactly the same thing as simply doing

```
new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => i.ToString()).OrderBy(i => i);
```

in the first place. Even if you were doing some actual processing in your `ProcessCollection` method, you'd usually simply use something like this:

```
new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.Process().Select(i => i.ToString()).OrderBy(i => i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> li = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    Func<int, bool> whereFilter = x => x % 2 == 0;
    Func<int, string> orderByClause = x => x.ToString();

    ProcessCollection(li, whereFilter, orderByClause); // 10, 2, 4, 6, 8
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> ProcessCollection<TSource, TResult>(     
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> whereFilter = null, 
    Func<TSource, TResult> orderByClause = null)
{
    if (whereFilter != null) source = source.Where(whereFilter);
    if (orderByClause != null) source = source.OrderBy(orderByClause);

    return source;
}
```